# Add class when more page is visited

Tags: css, session, body-class

I would like to add a CSS class to the body if a visitor goes to the second or third etc. page of the website. Or vice-versa: add a class only on the first visited page. The goal is that I can distinguish the first visited page.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this? Javascript? WP_SESSIONS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for **body_class()**

You can read more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/)

A solution for adding a body class to a specific page template:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
if ( is_page_template( 'page-example.php' ) ) {
    $classes[] = 'example';
}
return $classes;
}
```

The result on the front-end:

```
<body class="page page-id-7 page-template page-template-page-example page-template-page-example-php example">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use cookies in your functions.php file.

```
<?php
  function customprefix_body_class_filter() {
    $classes[] = 'has-seen-website';
    return $classes;
  }


  $has_seen_website = filter_input( INPUT_COOKIE, 'has_seen_website' );
  if ( !empty( $has_seen_website ) ) {
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'customprefix_body_class_filter' );
  }
  setcookie('has_seen_website', '1', time()+3600*24); // expires in 24 hours 
?>
```

Comment: Can I use WP_SESSION also?

Comment: Yes you could. The cookie could live longer, depending on the duration you're giving :)